# VPN metrics in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-vpc

Recently I have configured the ALARM in Cloudwatch for tracking VPN Tunnel connection. It is well known that 0 indicates tunnel is DOWN and 1 indicates tunnel is UP. When Connection is down, I have seen some data points on the graph shown as 0.66, 0.75.

So what does that mean, is the connection is DOWN or UP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statistic for each metric depends on your use case, and the underling metric.

From [CloudWatch Concepts - Statistics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Statistic)

> Statistics are metric data aggregations over specified periods of
>   time. CloudWatch provides statistics based on the metric data points
>   provided by your custom data or provided by other AWS services to
>   CloudWatch. Aggregations are made using the namespace, metric name,
>   dimensions, and the data point unit of measure, within the time period
>   you specify. The following table describes the available statistics.

Given the VPN metric above, try using the `Maximum` or `Minimum` statistics for the alarm. You are using the Average statistic, which, as you noted, will not produce meaningful data for your use case.

- **Minimum**
  The lowest value observed during the specified period. You can use this value to determine low volumes of activity for your application.
- **Maximum**
  The highest value observed during the specified period. You can use this value to determine high volumes of activity for your application.

Comment: I think Statistic: Minimum will helpful in my case. Because it will show me least value 0 and 1 as well in the given period. Where Maximum will give me only 1 always. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That happens if your graph shows averages (that is why both of your values are between 1 and 0). In the ClouWatch console select your metric and then click on the Graphed metrics tab. There you will see `Statistics` column which is most likely set to `Average` now.